# Multithreading: How to check if static class is busy

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a static class and it has a static function IsDataCorrect() which does a http request.

The function can be called from multiple threads at the same time, and I want to let the first thread doing the request, and the others should be rejected (meaning they should get false as return value, they should not just be blocked!) until half a second after the first thread finished the request.

After that, the next winning thread should be able to do the next request, others should be rejected, and so on.

This is my approach, could someone please confirm if that is reasonable:

```
static class MyClass
{
    private static bool IsBusy = false;

    private static object lockObject = new object();

    public static bool IsDataCorrect(string testString)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (IsBusy) return false;
            IsBusy = true;
        }

        var uri = $"https://something.com";

        bool htmlCheck = GetDocFromUri(uri, 2);

        var t = new Thread(WaitBeforeFree);
        t.Start();

        //Fast Evaluations
        //...           

        return htmlCheck;
    }

    private static void WaitBeforeFree()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using lock in `WaitBeforeFree()`? I'd also add the `volatile` keyword to the `IsBusy` member.

Comment: The idea was that only the winning thread can reach that part anyway so for me there seemed no need to do that.

Comment: But you're getting/setting `IsBusy` in the thread that spins up that winning thread in `IsDataCorrect()`, so you have 2 threads getting/setting it.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing *any* of this on multiple threads. Getting a document from a server is I/O bound. Delaying an operation doesn't require an entire thread! You would not hire a worker to sleep for you! All of this workflow can be done via single threaded asynchrony.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments! I went with the solution below by LB2 which should cover all your objections I hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your threads accessing the function would still be serialized in access for checking `IsBusy` flag, since only one thread at a time would be able to check it due to synchronization on `lockObject`.  Instead, you can simply attempt to get a lock, and consequently, you don't need a flag since the lock itself will serve as the lock.  Second, I would replace launching of new thread every time just to sleep and reset the flag, and replace it with a check on `DateTime` field.

```
static class MyClass
{
    private static DateTime NextEntry = DateTime.Now;
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim timeLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    private static object lockObject = new object();

    public static bool IsDataCorrect(string testString)
    {
        bool tryEnterSuccess = false;
        try
        {
            try
            {
                timeLock.EnterReadLock()
                if (DateTime.Now < NextEntry) return false;
            }
            finally 
            {
                timeLock.ExitReadLock()
            }
            Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject, ref tryEnterSuccess);
            if (!tryEnterSuccess) return false;

            var uri = $"https://something.com";

            bool htmlCheck = GetDocFromUri(uri, 2);

            //Fast Evaluations
            //...           
            try
            {
                timeLock.EnterWriteLock()
                NextEntry = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500);
            } finally {
                timeLock.ExitWriteLock()
            }
            return htmlCheck;
        } finally {
            if (tryEnterSuccess) Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
        }
    }
}
```

More efficient this way for not launching new threads, DateTime access is safe and yet concurrent so threads only stop when absolutely have to.  Otherwise, everything keeps moving along with minimal resource usage.

Comment: @@B2 I get the point, thanks. I will go with your solution for the moment :)

Comment: Wait, I get an exception in the last finally block line with Monitor.Exit(lockObject): 'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException' occurred. Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
Could it be that this is raised when a thread which was not able to Enter it called that line? No Enter - therefore no Exit possible?

Comment: I guess the first "try {" should actually be placed right under the check for tryEnterSucess, before the line with "Var uri = $" ... Tried it out and it worked fine.

Comment: @flo, yes, a bug, that's what I get for writing code without compiler at 1am.  I just made the correction that should work.

Comment: thanks and if you put the declaration of the bool tryEnterSuccess BEFORE the first try then it will work perfectly ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see you guys solved the problem correctly, but I think that there is still room to make it correct, efficient and simple in same time:).
How about this way?

EDIT: Edit to make calming easier and part of the example.

```
public static class ConcurrentCoordinationExtension
{
    private static int _executing = 0;

    public static bool TryExecuteSequentially(this Action actionToExecute)
    {
        // compate _executing with zero, if zero, set 1,
        // return original value as result,
        // successfull entry then result is zero, non zero returned, then somebody is executing
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _executing, 1, 0) != 0) return false;

        try
        {
            actionToExecute.Invoke();
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _executing, 0);//
        }
    }

    public static bool TryExecuteSequentially(this Func<bool> actionToExecute)
    {
        // compate _executing with zero, if zero, set 1,
        // return original value as result,
        // successfull entry then result is zero, non zero returned, then somebody is executing
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _executing, 1, 0) != 0) return false;

        try
        {
            return actionToExecute.Invoke();
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _executing, 0);//
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime last = DateTime.MinValue;

        Func<bool> operation= () =>
        {
            //calming condition was not meant
            if (DateTime.UtcNow - last < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)) return false;
            last = DateTime.UtcNow;
            //some stuff you want to process sequentially
            return true;
        };

        operation.TryExecuteSequentially();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is certainly a way to do it, but I would argue against it being more efficient.  `CompareExchange`, albeit being a very short operation, is a one thread at a time operation and is thus a serialized access.  I may be wrong, but I think `EnterReadLock` is concurrent (only blocks if there is intent to acquire write lock).  So threads shouldn't be serializing access.  Second, your solution ignores the 500ms delay requirement that OP stated.

Comment: What is in your thinking a serialized access? It is not blocking threads and it is not spinning. It is translated into CPU atomic instructions. You do know, that atomic operations are intrinsically concurrent right? There is nothing else faster in c# to concurrently coordinate multiple threads. Btw,  those slim versions of synchronization primitives like ReaderWriterLockSlim are actually written on top of Interlocked operations. But here it is overkill.

Comment: I did not saw the need to nurture the bad design with the 500ms calmer, so I did not put it there. From the design point of view, calming some operation should not be concerned with concurrent serializing of the operation! It is mixing multiple concerns together. The calmer should be preceding the call to the concurrent serializer and when calmer conditions are met, then the concurrent operation should be attempted to execute.

Comment: yes I know that atomic operations are concurrent. In fact I at first thought that timestamp might not need to be protected so long as it fits into a word of the processor, but couldn't remember structur size. AFAIK, and again I'm not certain and can be wrong, interlock will block thread if two try to change value at same time. Briefly. I thought also that readwritelock doesn't block issuing read access (unless pending write) and two threads can simultaneously request read access (as in process of requesting vs owning). If they're backed by interlock then indeed no difference.

Comment: by the way, I agree that 500 ms cool off is weird. I'm questioning the rationale behind it too, but I allowed for some constraint or reasoning that we're not privy to. it's valid to question it and I'd concur on that.

Comment: Interlocked operations are CPU atomic instructions and these do not care about threads. They do not reach far complexities of the operating system and its locking mechanisms between threads. They are not concerned about threads, they are concerned only about concurrent access to given memory address by multiple cores and CPU architecture simply guarantees, that multiple concurrently running atomic instructions will behave as if these instructions would be running sequentially. Those threads which executed these instructions on multiple cores are not going to sense any difference.

Comment: The meaning of the term "blocking" is most often used for threads, blocking or not blocking concurrent access, blocking is causing some threads to sleep and wait. Not applicable to interlocking operations.

Comment: What happens when two threads try to interlock on the variable at the same exact time?  Wouldn't one be blocked until the other is finished with interlock?

Comment: Thread blocking is a high level operating system construct, as I said, interlocked instructions do not know how to block in first place. Thread blocking is always done by calling OS functions and they decide about blocking the thread, letting it wait in some synchronization primitive's specific queue. Interlocked methods are translated to simple atomic CPU instructions. How could they know how to block a thread? They do not call OS functions, they do not even know how.

Comment: Simply one instruction will be little slower, taking few more CPU cycles to compute.

Comment: @LB2 Are you satisfied with the answer/reasoning or you are not happy yet:).

Comment: LOL, I tried to lookup implementation details of Interlock, but of course it is implemented in mscorlib, so I can't really see (at least not with dotPeek).  Yes, I completely understand atomicity of CPU instructions and I introduced confusion here with the word "blocking".  Yes, there is OS level thread blocking (not candidate for execution scheduling), but I meant generically from execution.  As you mentioned hardware architecture doesn't allow write to the same memory location on the same instruction clock by two CPUs. One will have to skip at least one clock cycle (at hardware level).

Comment: So essentially a kind of (very short) block.  I thought that rw-lock can do the read grant for two threads without running into the same h/w sync - I just looked further and it's not - it does the same Interlock exchange is you do.  So your solution is admittedly far more elegant as rwlock is heavier in its processing, and acknowledged with +1 for your answer :) .

Comment: Thanks LB2,though I think you are wasting your click on me.I kinda asked because I am about to leave stackoverflow account for good. but hate to leave discussion in limbo.I was banned from posting questions,they are usually niche in nature, very specific or low interest,so not much votes and some questions were closed or downvoted usually by silly people with credentials in html, css, javascript, ruby on Heels :) or something else. jsut not peers with C#, C, C++, .Net credentials. It is peer review turned on its head, usually done by people fishing for badges for stackoverflow account...

Comment: And I even publicly commented mine questions and others questions, why they were downvoted or closed for no apparent reason by people that can not be considered peers, so it seems I stepped on some pressure points...